# How to show a message with command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a multiplayer server with my friends and I want to create a command block that when a player dies to show in the chat or on the screen a message for example: "Press F to pay respects".

Comment: Please clarify. Are you asking how to print the message, how to detect the death of players, or both?

Answer (score -1):

try the command /say. For example, if you want it to say Press F to pay respects, to /say Press F to pay respects. If that doesn't work, try putting the message in quotes.